# wp_head is effecting my slider

Tags: wordpress

i was trying to make my image maps responsive. For that When no any mannual way I got then I start looking for wordpress plugin and i found many.

But problem is that to make those plugins (img map responsive) to work I have to put `wp_head()` in header section. But by putting `wp_head()` my slider stopped working.i have tried a lot but couldn't come up with any solution.

> So what i want ?

Either a way to make image map responsive without a plugin.

OR Any way in which I can put my `wp_head()` without effecting my slider.The slider which I am using is not a plugin. It is Bootstrap carousel manually added.

Any suggetion will be appriciable.

> UPDATE

I need one JS file to be free from the effect of `wp_head()/wp_fotter()` that is `<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/layout/scripts/tabslet/jquery.tabslet.min.js"></script>`.

By putting wp_head/footer this file dont load. if it can load by any trick then my problem will get resolved.

Comment: Are there any console errors(javascript)?

Comment: There is not error msg. Just my slider stopped its functionality.